# With reference to an action between sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I came up with the following question regarding the classification of groups of order $p^2qr$ considered in pages 11,12 and 13 in the following attached article.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.02616.pdf

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^2qr$, where $p,q,r$ are distinct primes. Let $F$ be a fitting subgroup of $G$. Then both $F$ and $G/F$ are both non-trivial and $G/F$ acts faithfully on $\bar{F}:=F/\phi(F)$ so that no non-trivial normal subgroup of $G/F$ stabilizes a series through $\bar{F}$.

When $|F|=pr$, $\phi(F) = 1$ and $Aut(F) = C_{p−1} \times C_{r−1}$. Thus $G/F$ is abelian and hence $G/F \cong C_p \times C_q$. It follows that $p | (r − 1)$ and $q | (p − 1)(r − 1)$.

There are two cases to distinguish. First, suppose that the Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G/F$ acts non-trivially on the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $F$.

What is meant by "Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G/F$ acts non-trivially on the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $F$"? Where can I find a good knowledge about such an action?

Can someone please help to understand this question?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: My main problem is that they speak of *the* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $F$. Why can we exclude that there are $r$ of them?

Comment: Yes, I'm also confused about that part too.

Comment: I thought that may be the action is only on the sylow $p$ subgroup. But I don't understand how it is happening. Please help

Comment: The Fitting subgroup is nilpotent, so has only one Sylow-$p$-subgroup.

Comment: Yes, and also has only one sylow $r$-subgroup, right? But what is meant by acting non trivially?

Comment: $G$ acts on $F$ by conjugation, so (as its Sylow-subgroups are charactersitic) acts on the Sylow-$p$-subgroup $P$ of $F$ by conjugation. Now $F$ centralises $P$, so this action by conjugation yields a well-defined action of $G/F$ on $P$. Restrict attention to the Sylow-$q$-subgroup and we have the action he's talking about. "Non-trivial" means that the Sylow-$q$-subgroup does not centralise $P$.

Comment: Thank you @ancientmathematician and

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Then $G \cong (C_p \times C_r) \rtimes (C_p \times Cq)$, right? and if $C_q$ acts trivially on $C_p$, $G \cong (C_p \times C_r) \rtimes (C_p \times Cq)$, right?

Comment: I think that's right, but I'd have to check that in the case in question the Sylow-$p$-subgroup of $G$ can't be cyclic - I'm sure that's so but it needs proof.

Comment: Thanks @ancientmathematician can we say that $(C_p \times C_r) \rtimes (C_p \times C_q)$ is the only group present up to isomorphism when $|F|=pr$?

Comment: Can you also guide me to prove in the case that the sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ can't be cyclic?

Comment: I do not think you should say this : $(C_p \times C_r) \rtimes (C_p \times C_q)$  is *the only* group present up to isomorphism when $|F|=pr$. There may be various possible actions on $F$, giving different groups $G$. For instance, I think there are three split extensions of $C_7\times C_{43}$ by $C_3\times C_7$ with $|F|=301$.

Comment: As to the cyclic $p$ subgroup case, I really think that you'd do better first to fully understand some easier cases: for instance the groups of order $3^2\cdot 7$ with Fitting subgroup $C_{21}$. When the Sylow $3$-subgroup is cyclic a generator $x$ cubes to an element of order $3$ in $F$, and acts on a generator $h$ of $C_7$ by $h^x=h^2$ - this now describes the group completely. The same sort of thing happens in the groups of order $p^2 qr$.

Comment: But then those three are also written as $(C_7 \times C_{43}) \rtimes_{\theta_1} (C_3 \times C_7)$, $(C_7 \times C_{43}) \rtimes_{\theta_2} (C_3 \times C_7)$ and $(C_7 \times C_{43}) \rtimes_{\theta_3} (C_3 \times C_7)$ for $\theta_1:(C_3 \times C_7) \rightarrow Aut(C_7 \times C_{43})$, $\theta_2:(C_3 \times C_7) \rightarrow Aut(C_7 \times C_{43})$ and $\theta_3:(C_3 \times C_7) \rightarrow Aut(C_7 \times C_{43})$, right?

Comment: Yes, I was only saying that you shouldn't say  "the only".

Comment: Ok, that means that the representation is as above but there are many semidirect products?

Comment: I wanted to clarify whether there can be other representations as well @ancientmathematician

Comment: The number of possibilities depends on whether $p|(r-1)$ and $q|(p-1)(r-1)$.

Comment: I don't understand "representation".

Comment: I meant that when writing using notations/symbols, we always write $(C_p \times C_r)$ semidirect product $(C_p \times C_q)$. Can there be any other ways of writing groups under this case like $(C_p \rtimes C_r) \rtimes (C_p \times C_q)$?

Comment: There's nothing unique about it. For instance one of the groups of order $7^2\cdot3\cdot 43$ is more easily written as $C_7\times (C_{43}\rtimes C_{21})$. You'll learn more if you look closely yourself at specific examples before dashing off these questions.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much @ancientmathematician